# Instructor for a Course provided by Organization in Schema.org

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I'm adding structured data to a course web page using [`Course`](https://schema.org/Course) json-ld markup.

The "provider" field I think is our Organization, because is an online course on our platform and we prepare the material to show during the lessons or, if this material is prepared from the Instructor/Speaker, is subject to approval/editing.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "Course",
  "name": "Introduction to Trading Online",
  "description": "Introductory Trading Online course laying out the basics.",
  "image":"https://investire.biz/img/course/1500202_d7cc.jpg",
  "provider": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "Investire.biz",
    "sameAs": "https://investire.biz"
  },
  "inLanguage": "English",
  "audience":{"audienceType":["Beginner trader","No specific knowledge"],"@type":"Audience"}
}
</script>
```

Which is **the correct field for the instructor or speaker**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Course` can’t have a speaker, because it represents the creative work, not a specific instance of this course.

You can provide the instances with the [`hasCourseInstance`](https://schema.org/hasCourseInstance) property, which takes [`CourseInstance`](https://schema.org/CourseInstance) as value.

And a `CourseInstance` can have the [`instructor`](https://schema.org/instructor) property:

> A person assigned to instruct or provide instructional assistance for the `CourseInstance`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately the hasCourseInstance is valid in [structured data testing tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) only if a location is provided, in my case is an online course, so I think that location for the course is inappropriate.
At the end I used the "creator" property that in my case is the same person as the speaker/instructor.

Comment: @JackSoftyweb: You can ignore this error in the SDTT. It doesn’t mean that the code is invalid -- it means that the code isn’t eligible for Google’s [event rich result](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/event?hl=en).